# Migração php 5.4 para 5.6

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho um servidor com php 5.4 e precisava fazer um upgrade pro php 5.6 pra poder rodar o cake 3.
Acontece que o cliente tem um sistema com php puro rodando nessa versão antiga e agora está com receio de fazer esse upgrade e acabar parando as coisas ja existentes.

Alguém sabe se a mudança do 5.4 pro 5.6 é muito drástica, qual a probabilidade de parar o que existe hoje?

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 0):

Você pode manter a versão do PHP 5.4 e as apicações não terão problemas pra rodar na versão 5.6. E vice versa.

o ambiente de desenvolvimento pode ser PHP 5.4 ou PH|P 5.6 e o ambiente de produção pode ser desde a versão PHP 5.3 até a versão PHP 5.6 claro exceto aplicações que utilizem recursos extintos para as versões mais novas ou novos para as versões mais antigas.

Mas você tambem pode rodas duas versões diferentes do php no mesmo servidor se preferir.